# Using <%: %> or <%= %> in tag's inline style attribute

Tags: css, asp.net, html

I have a `<div>` and I want to set the height of it to the user control's `MyHeight` property.  It seems I can do this with `<div height="<%= MyHeight %>">`, but I'd rather use the `style` attribute because `height` isn't a valid attribute in HTML5.

For some reason--and I haven't found why on the web--doing `<div style="height: <%= MyHeight %>px">` renders the literal '<%= MyHeight %>' rather than replacing it with the backend value.  The same goes for using `<%: MyHeight %>`.  Oddly, it even works for `<div foobar="<%= MyHeight %>px">`.  The `style` attribute seems to be special.

Aside from setting the height, there is no reason that this div needs to be a server control, so I don't want to add `runat="server"`.  My workaround had been to use

```
<style>
    #myDiv {
        height: <%= MyHeight %>px;
    }
</style>
...
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Beside being tedious, this doesn't work if I want to use the control multiple times, since they would have the same ID.  I'd again have to do `runat="server"`.

Can someone explain to me why it works for the `height` attribute, but not the `style` attribute, and if there is a way to do what I want?

### Edit

It turns out that I was wrong.  Using `<div style="height: <%= MyHeight %>px">` does in fact work.  VS says it doesn't, and it doesn't if you do use `runat="server"`, which I had been using as a work-around until I figured this out.  I've run into similar situations in the past (though I don't quite remember what they were), so VS + my workaround in place + my memory caused me to write this.

Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Is this inside `<head runat="server">`?

Comment: The div?  No, the div is in the body.

Comment: This seems to work for me: `<div style="height: <%= 10 %>px"></div>` renders `<div style="height: 10px"></div>`.  Is your tag inside a control that you are doing data binding with?  Something seems off.

Comment: You're right.  It is working.  I think the issue is that I had been using runat="server" as a workaround, which doesn't work, and VS's text editor marks it as an invalid value (which isn't the cause with any other attribute).  Those plus memory of a similar situation, made me think it wasn't working.

Answer (score 2):

Try using an inline style attribute instead:

```
<div style="height: <%= MyHeight %>px"></div>
```

Comment: That's literally exactly what I tried.  It's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You could also pass a asp variable to Javascript, then use Javascript to modify your page using:

`var my_height = "<%= MyProperty %>";`

and change the div height using

`document.getElementById('myDiv').style.height = my_height + "px";`

Example:

```
<script>
    var my_height = "<%= MyProperty %>";
    function setheight() {
    document.getElementById('myDiv').style.height = my_height + "px";   
    }
</script>
<body onload="setheight()">
<div id="myDiv"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work if I have multiple instances of the UserControl because I would have multiple instances of the same ID.

Comment: Why have multiple's of the same id, that in it self is bad practice!

Comment: Your id should be a unique identifier, why not make different `ID` and use the same class?

Comment: @dfoverdx why not edit your question so we all stop wasting our time?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using a placeholder instead:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ctrl = new HtmlGenericControl("style");
        string height = "100"; //or whatever
        ctrl.InnerHtml = string.format("div {height: {0}px;}", height);
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(ctrl); //where PlaceHolder1 is defined on page
    }
```

Comment: Well, the goal was to avoid using server-side code for something so simple.